# 2 GCE instances are created by 2 service account on different subnet cannot talk each other

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine

I'm settings up google cloud for my works. I have issue related to `service account` and `vpc network`. The detail is: 2 GCE instances are created by 2 `service accounts` on different `subnet` in same `VPC`, but they cannot talk each other.

**Context:**

- `GCE` instance with name `test01` and `test03` are created by `one service account` but different subnet (`sub1`/`sub2`)
- `GCE` instance `test02` is created by `another service account` in subnet `sub1`
- Firewall allow ping for all targets from all source

**Result**

- `test01` and `test02` can ping each other. Same subnet, different service account
- `test01` and `test03` can ping each other. Different subnet, same service account
- `test02` and `test03` cannot ping each other. Different subnet, different service account

Answer (score 0):

I might start checking if the Services Accounts has the same roles and privileges among the projects.

Also please check if the Network Tags attached to the VM instances are correct (syntax) and the corresponding Firewall rules for ingress/egress are allowing the icmp traffic.

You can check [Firewall rules in GCP: Source and Target filtering by Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#serviceaccounts) and [Filtering by service account vs. network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#service-accounts-vs-tags) for more details. Please note you cannot mix and match service accounts and network tags in any firewall rule.

I recommend you to review the Use Cases for Ingress and Egress described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#gcp_firewall_use_cases).

Additionally, in this document are described common scenarios where [Multiple Network Interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/multiple-interfaces-concepts#top_of_page) are used. It might help you to build a Networking and virtual appliances by different Nic devices, Shared VPC and so on.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I already mentioned **Firewall allow ping for all targets from all source**. So firewall is not problem in my case. Furthermore, when apply `firewall rule` I already can see 3 GCE instances that follow a rule.

Comment: 1. For the test02 and test03, on the "Network details", double check each Egress and Ingress firewall rules and Routes configuration.
2. Compare the configuration amoun the 3 VMs.